# How to safely synchronize two folders without duplicates?

Tags: bash, sync, rsync

I have an account on mega and I want to synchronize it with a folder on my computer. The problem is, that this account is public to some extent so I can't just use `rsync` with `--delete` in case someone just deleted all files.

I thought that it might be possible to `rsync` all files to my computer without deleting anything, then find duplicates (someone moved files to another directory, etc.) using command `find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 33 | cut -c 35-` and keep just the newest version.

But If I'm not mistaken time of creation of file is left after copying. That is unfortunate because the data mostly consists of images and pdf files which don't change.

Is there any way to pass (only) copied files to `touch` for example or any better way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You said :

> But If I'm not mistaken time of creation of file is left after copying.

Not always.

When you copy files and directories you can preserve the modification times.
e.g. `cp -rp` preserve time creation, ownership...   (from `man cp`):

> -a, --archive       same as -dR --preserve=all
>      -p                  same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

---

At the same way `rsync -t` preserve  modification times (this time from `man rsync`):

> **-t**, --times    **preserve modification times**

Usually `rsync` is used with `-avr` options so with an implicit `-t` use.

> **-a**, --archive  archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)

Comment: So I can use just rsync (without -t) and delete older files from the list generated by that command?

Comment: For me is a little bit unclear what you want. BTW if you copy the first time with `cp -rp` or `scp -rp` this will preserve time of creation. Then if you rsync with `rsync -avr`  you will update the only the new ones, preserving again the times. If you need to delete some files there are not present on  _the receiving side (ones that aren't on the sending side)_ you can use the option `rsync -avr --delete`. But check carefully what you are doing with a DRY RUN (`-n`) before (using `rsync -avr --delete` __`-n`__) , and do local test to check that you wrote all correctly.

Comment: I want to keep all files in case someone deleted anything (it's possible, account is shared) but if someone else just moved files to another location in tree I don't want to keep duplicit files

Comment: Ok I suggest you this strategy: Start with a clean syncronized copy (`scp -rp ...`), let's we say today. Then create an ordered list of md5 checksum for local files. STOP. Tomorrow (when you will check for an update) do a DRY RUN with ` rsync -a --list-only ... ...  `. Parse the output to create a list on which you will redo the md5sum for the remote files on the remote path.  Then work on the 2 lists updating the files and the local md5sum list. I suggest you to create a LOCK mechanism to avoid problems.